# How to get the Freeman chain code in OpenCV?

Tags: c++, opencv

I am trying to obtain the Freeman chain code using the `findCountours` function but I'm unable to understand its parameters, and an explanation is not given for each parameter in the [OpenCV documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/structural_analysis_and_shape_descriptors.html?highlight=findcontours#approxchains).

Can anyone assist me?

Comment: oh please, if you can, avoid the outdated c-api.

Comment: @berak can you suggest the new useful API for that and any function call to get chaincode i n opencv

Comment: no idea what you're doing there, but a combination of findContours and appoxPolyDP seems more approriate usually

Comment: i am getting the contours using findContours properly but i want chaincode to extract feature of that contour. the chaincode will be taken as an input to the fourier transform to get scale and rotation invariant features

Answer (score 1):

Using this function you'll get contour from Freeman chain. It will not give you freeman chain, it gets it as input.

I dont know why there is no cv::CHAIN_CODE (it equals 0) in current version of OpenCV but I've checked

```
vector<vector<cv::Point>> c;
cv::findContours(Img,c,RETR_EXTERNAL,0 );
```

works well. And gives full freman code for contours.

You also can use this old API code:

```
CvChain* chain=0;
CvMemStorage* storage=0;
storage=cvCreateMemStorage(0);
cvFindContours( &IplImage(Img), storage, (CvSeq**)(&chain), sizeof(*chain), CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_CODE );

for(;chain!=NULL;chain=(CvChain*)chain ->h_next) 
{   
    //chain=(CvChain*)chain ->h_next; 
    //if(chain==NULL){break;}
    CvSeqReader reader; 
    int i, total = chain->total; 
    cvStartReadSeq((CvSeq*)chain,&reader,0); 
    printf("--------------------chain\n"); 

    for(i=0;i<total;i++) 
    { 
        char code; 
        CV_READ_SEQ_ELEM(code, reader); 
        printf("%d",code); 
    } 
}
```

Comment: is there any method in opencv to retrieve chain code for polygonal curve?

Comment: You can retrive Freeman code with method I've wrote in updated answer (with approximation method flag set to zero).

Comment: this is the solution for python!!

Comment: Thats not python, thats C++ (it gives the result in strange form). I've updated my answer with old C-API code (I've tested it, and it works fine).

Comment: i am using opencv2.4.8 , how can i use old API with new version? this code giving me error may be because of cvFindContours( &IplImage(Img), storage, (CvSeq**)(&chain), sizeof(*chain), CV_RETR_EXTERNAL, CV_CHAIN_CODE );CV_CHAIN_CODE is not available in newer version

Comment: Add header #include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h"