# How to get the Chain Code from OpenCVs findContours method

Tags: java, opencv

I already have spend some time trying to implement a chain code from a contour of a plant's leaf until I came across [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22326412/how-to-get-the-freeman-chain-code-in-opencv/22326689#22326689) which claimed that the OpenCV method `findContours` can be used to find the chain code. 
So far I have this code:

```
public static List<MatOfPoint> chainCode;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    // load the Core OpenCV library by name
    System.loadLibrary(Core.NATIVE_LIBRARY_NAME);

    // create a display window
    Imshow window1 = new Imshow("My Image - original");

    // load an image from file (read and decode JPEG file)
    Mat inputImg = Highgui.imread("files/11. Acer palmaturu/iPAD2_C11_EX01.JPG");
    Mat grayImg = new Mat(inputImg.height(), inputImg.width(), CvType.CV_8UC1);

    //turn into binary image and invert
    Imgproc.cvtColor(inputImg, grayImg, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
    Imgproc.threshold(grayImg, grayImg, 0, 255, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY | Imgproc.THRESH_OTSU);
    Mat invertcolormatrix= new Mat(grayImg.rows(),grayImg.cols(), grayImg.type(), new Scalar(255,255,255));
    Core.subtract(invertcolormatrix, grayImg, grayImg);

    //get chain code
    chainCode = new Vector<MatOfPoint>();
    Imgproc.findContours(grayImg, chainCode, new Mat(), Imgproc.RETR_EXTERNAL, Imgproc.CHAIN_APPROX_NONE);

    //loop through indices of individual contours to find largest contour
    double largest_area = 0;
    int largest_contour_index = 0;
    for(int i = 0; i< chainCode.size(); i++){
        //find the area of the contour
        double a = Imgproc.contourArea(chainCode.get(i),false); 
        //find largest contour and it's index
        if(a > largest_area){
            largest_area= a;
            largest_contour_index = i;    
        }
     }

    //draw largest contour
    if(chainCode.size() > 0){
        Imgproc.drawContours(inputImg, chainCode, largest_contour_index, new Scalar (0, 0, 255), 1);
        System.out.println("chain code at " + largest_contour_index + "; " + chainCode.get(largest_contour_index));
    }

    //show image
    window1.showImage(inputImg);
}
```

Right now I am stuck from where I can get the original chain code as in V = 000567454....
Or should I try it with a completely different approach? Can anybody give me some help on this please as I am really stuck!

I want to use the chain code for further processing and image recognition with a Fourier transform later on.

Comment: You don't get the chain, but the values of the chain, i.e. the Points of the contour. If you need the actual chain, you can iterate over points and find if its on top, left, etc...

Comment: oh of course, thank you for helping my with the stupid mistake :)